# How to create high priority bounded subqueue and low priority bounded subqueue in JAVA

Tags: java, collections, priority-queue

I have created a priority queue and filled the queue with items and using this queue as basis I iterated through it and found the priority of the items. Depending on the priority am moving items to subqueues using some logic.

In my main program I created bounded subqueues using static statements what I would like to do is create the bounded subqueue using the constructor of my parent queue Constructor: `public HiLoPriorityQueue(int high_capacity, int low_capacity)`
the constructor should create high priority bounded sub-queue with initial capacity high_capacity and a low priority bounded sub-queue with capacity low_capacity

Can the subqueues be created from parent queue by using the same add and remove methods applied on the parent queue??

My Main Program:

```
   public class PQTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        HiLoPriorityQueue<Customer>  prq = new HiLoPriorityQueue<Customer>(10); 
        Customer c1 = new Customer("Rock",999);
        Customer c2 = new Customer("Brock",1);
        Customer c3 = new Customer("UnderTaker",1000);

        HiLoPriorityQueue<Customer>  hq = new HiLoPriorityQueue<Customer>(5);
        HiLoPriorityQueue<Customer>  lq = new HiLoPriorityQueue<Customer>(3);


        // insert values in the queue
        prq.add(c1);
        prq.add(c2);
        prq.add(c3);


        // create iterator from the queue
        Iterator it = prq.iterator();

        System.out.println ( "Priority queue values are: ");
        while (it.hasNext()){
            Customer c = (Customer) it.next();
            System.out.println ( "Value: "+ c);
            System.out.println("Priority is :: "+c.getPriority());
            if(c.getPriority() == 1){
                if(hq.size() < 5 )
                    hq.add(c);
                else{
                    if(hq.size() < 5 )  lq.add(c);
                    else{
                        lq.remove();
                        lq.add(c);
                    }
                }
            }
            else{
                if(lq.size() < 3)   lq.add(c);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Queue creation class:

```
public class HiLoPriorityQueue<E extends BinaryPrioritizable> extends AbstractCollection{

private int count;
private Object[] elements;
private Object[] helements;
private Object[] lelements;
private int head;
private int tail;

public HiLoPriorityQueue(int high_capacity, int low_capacity){
    helements = new Object[high_capacity];
    lelements = new Object[low_capacity];
    count = 0;
    head = 0;
    tail = 0;       
}

public HiLoPriorityQueue(int capacity)
{
    elements = new Object[capacity];
    count = 0;
    head = 0;
    tail = 0;
}



@Override
public Iterator<E> iterator()
     {
        return new Iterator<E>()
         {
         public boolean hasNext()
         {
         return visited < count;
         }

         public E next()
         {
         int index = (head + visited) % elements.length;
         E r = (E) elements[index];
         visited++;
         return r;
         }

         public void remove()
         {
         throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
         }

         private int visited = 0;
     };
     }

 public boolean add(E anObject)
 {
     elements[tail] = anObject;
     tail = (tail + 1) % elements.length;
     count++;
     return true;
 }

 public E remove()
 {
     E r = (E) elements[head];
     head = (head + 1) % elements.length;
     count--;
     return r;
 } 

@Override
 public int size()
 {
    return count;
 }



}
```

Comment: "Can the subqueues be created from parent queue by using the same add and remove methods applied on the parent queue??" - This seems straight forward. Have you tried and and are you facing any issues?

Comment: public HiLoPriorityQueue(int high_capacity, int low_capacity){
  helements = new Object[high_capacity];
  lelements = new Object[low_capacity];
  hq = new HiLoPriorityQueue<Customer>(high_capacity);
  lq = new HiLoPriorityQueue<Customer>(low_capacity);
  count = 0;
  head = 0;
  tail = 0;  
 }  This is the constructor I created and when I say in my logic hq.add(c) the parent queue gets added up but not the subqueue :(

Comment: I see that - but you don't have code in there to create the 2 child queues.

Comment: Will this statement not create a child queue for parent priority queue "prq" ??------                                                                                                         hq = new HiLoPriorityQueue<Customer>(high_capacity);

Answer (score 0):

Your code makes little sense. Why are you using `Object[]` arrays to hold your elements in your `HiLoPriorityQueue` class? Using a `Object` array is generally a bad idea and I think it would make more sense to use `ArrayList<E extends BinaryPrioritizable>` as per your class specification. Secondly, why do you have `helements` and `lelements` since they are never being used?

> Can the subqueues be created from parent queue by using the same add and remove methods applied on the parent queue??

The answer to this question yes, since your parent queue is the same type as your sub-queues. But I'm not entirely sure if this is what you're asking or not, neither am I entirely sure what you're trying to do.

If I've understood you correctly, however, I think you're trying to keep a low priority queue and a high priority queue. These should go inside your `HiLoPriorityQueue` class and be handled internally whenever a user `adds/removes` data. Your priority separation logic should go inside the `add()` method of your `HiLoPriorityQueue` class.

Finally, if you want a data structure such that all high-priority elements are handled before the low priority elements you should just use a built in `MaxHeap` (i.e `PirorityQueue<Customer> q = new PriorityQueue<Customer>()`) where you specify a comparator.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yup you understood correctly.... I was trying to keep a low priority queue and a high priority queue inside HiLoPriorityQueue....Will follow your advise I try to modify my code. Thanks.

Comment: I updated my code as per your suggestions and it works fine now. Here is the updated code in git hub                               https://github.com/kakarrot007/PriorityQueue....... Appreciate suggestions or feedback from all to improve my code.

Comment: @ Dex, just too a look at your code. I think you should look at  some implementations of data structures, particularly heaps/queues to see how they are implemented underneath to get a better understanding of how to go about implementing yours. I'm not sure how new you are to programming/java and what your code is for (learning, some app your building, etc) but your implementation is not exactly well coded.